# Using sed to remove all lines containing special characters , numbers, and spaces

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

So I'm fairly new to using shell--bash specifically--and I'm in the process of writing a script which will translate files containing DNA sequences into a more useful format. Unfortunately, many of these files will contain extraneous lines used for labeling information, etc. I need a sed command that will exclude these lines containing special character, numbers, or spaces. I've found that it is fairly straightforwards removing lines with spaces by using

```
sed '/ /d' infile
```

and I imagine that removing lines containing numbers will be a similar strategy using regex. I just haven't really found any way of approaching special characters in sed.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on what you mean by special characters, you might be better of deleting everything *but* a set of characters. For example, to delete all non-alphabetic characters: `sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]//g'`.

Comment: It will be much understandable if could provide some example lines and your desired output..

Comment: I think I have it figured out, I simply altered my sed to look like this `sed '/[[:alpha:]]//!d' infile ` which--if the logic follows--should exclude any line containing anything except [A-Za-z]

Answer (score 4):

To delete any line that is not composed entirely of alphabetic characters, you'd need to add start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors

```
sed '/^[[:alpha:]]*$/!d' file
```

Instead, you could delete any line that contains at least one non-alphabetic character

```
sed '/[^[:alpha:]]/d' file
```

Note that the caret `^` is acting as a negation operator here rather than as an anchor as in the previous expression.

---

Alternatively, using grep's whole-line (`-x` or `--line-regexp`) option

```
grep -x '[[:alpha:]]*' file
```

(equivalent of the first sed expression) or using an inverse match (`-v`)

```
grep -v '[^[:alpha:]]' file
```

(equivalent of the second sed expression).

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from OPs comment

> I think I have it figured out, I simply altered my `sed` to look
>   like this `sed '/[[:alpha:]]//!d' infile` which--if the logic
>   follows--should exclude any line containing anything except `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: I don't think that's a well-formed sed expression (`/[[:alpha:]]/!d` would be, but would allow any line containing at least one alphabetic character)

Comment: @steeldriver I have not tested, so it is a community wiki. Feel free to downvote =)